# Download two URLs at once but process as soon as one completes

Tags: javascript, concurrency, axios

I have two API urls to hit. One known to be fast (~50-100ms). One known to be slow (~1s). I use the results of these to display product choices to the user. Currently I await-download one, then do the second. Pretty synchronous and because of that it's adding 50-100ms to the already-slow second hit.

I would like to:

- Send both requests at once
- Start processing data as soon as one request comes back
- Wait for both requests before moving on from there.

I've seen the example Axios give...

```
axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

But this *appears* to wait for both URLs to commit. This would still be marginally faster but I want the data from my 50ms API hit to start showing as soon as it's ready.

Answer (score 2):

For sure you can chain additional `.then`s to the promises returned by axios:

```
  Promise.all([
    getUserAccount()
      .then(processAccount),
    getUserPermissions()
      .then(processPermissions)
  ]).then(([userAccount, permissions]) => {
     //...
  });
```

wereas `processAccount` and `processPermissions` are functions that take the axios response object as an argument and return the wanted results.

For sure you can also add multiple `.then`s to the same promise:

```
  const account = getUserAccount();
  const permissions = getUserPermissions();

  // Show permissions when ready
  permissions.then(processPermissions);

  Promise.all([account, permissions])
  .then(([account, permissions]) => {
     // Do stuff when both are ready
  });
```

---

I replaced `axios.all` with `Promise.all` - I don't know why axios provides that helper as JS has a native implementation for that. I tried consulting the docs ... but they are not even documenting that API.

Comment: My bet is axios had an `all()` method before browsers had full Promise support similar to jQuery having `$.when` many years ago and long before Promises A+ spec

Comment: @charlieftl that was my thought too ... the docs should clearly mention that, but the library seems to have many open issues and very rudimentary documentation...

Comment: Might also mention OP can render in either of those process functions which sounds like the goal

Comment: Sure, there are various ways to chain these things together, that depends on the OPs exact usecase. I think the answer provides enough food for thought to dig in :)